# Job failed Exception hadoop

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I am using multi text output formate to create multiple files of a single file i.e each line on new file.

This is my code:

```
public class MOFExample extends Configured implements Tool {

private static double count = 0;

static class KeyBasedMultipleTextOutputFormat extends
        MultipleTextOutputFormat<Text, Text> {
    @Override
    protected String generateFileNameForKeyValue(Text key, Text value,
            String name) {
        return count++ + "_";// + name;
    }
}

/**
 * The main job driver.
 */
public int run(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path csvInputs = new Path(args[0]);
    Path outputDir = new Path(args[1]);

    JobConf jobConf = new JobConf(super.getConf());
    jobConf.setJarByClass(MOFExample.class);
    jobConf.setMapperClass(IdentityMapper.class);

    jobConf.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    jobConf.setOutputFormat(KeyBasedMultipleTextOutputFormat.class);
    jobConf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    jobConf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(jobConf, csvInputs);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jobConf, outputDir);
    //jobConf.setNumMapTasks(4);
    jobConf.setNumReduceTasks(4);
    return JobClient.runJob(jobConf).isSuccessful() ? 0 : 1;
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new MOFExample(), args);
    System.exit(res);
}
}
```

This code runs fine on small text file but when the number of lines of input file are greater than 1900 which is yet not a large file it throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:836)
>       at MOFExample.run(MOFExample.java:57)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>       at MOFExample.main(MOFExample.java:61)

I also tried [this tutorial](http://rajkrrsingh.blogspot.com/2013/11/mapreduce-writing-output-to-multiple.html) but this one returns empty output directory without any exception when the input file is large however this one also worked fine with small input file.

> Note: I am using Single-Node Cluster

Comment: can you include your code in a try block and print the stack trace?